# Drupal translation jquery

Tags: jquery, drupal, translation, drupal-8

I'm trying to use Drupals translation. **'/admin/config/regional/translate'**.
When I use the code in the bottom, the word are showing in the list and I can specify the translation.

But when I use the variable in may jQuery code i'm getting an error.

**Cannot read property 't' of undefined**

Maybe I need to define t ? or include it? 
I'm using Drupal 8

Doc: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/localization-api/translating-strings-in-javascript

```js
;(function ($, Drupal) {
    $(function () {

    function addLeadForm(){
        var title = Drupal.t("Fill to get demoversion");
        var firstName = Drupal.t("firstname");
        var lastName = Drupal.t("lastname");
        var email = Drupal.t("email");

   });
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I guess you forgot to include the right dependencies in your `*.libraries.yml`.

Here comes an example from `menu_ui.js`:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.menuUiDetailsSummaries = {
    attach: function attach(context) {
      $(context).find('.menu-link-form').drupalSetSummary(function (context) {
        var $context = $(context);
        if ($context.find('.js-form-item-menu-enabled input').is(':checked')) {
          return Drupal.checkPlain($context.find('.js-form-item-menu-title input').val());
        }

        return Drupal.t('Not in menu');
      });
    }
  };
```

And the corresponding `menu_ui.libraries.yml`:

```
drupal.menu_ui:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    menu_ui.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupal.form
```

Comment: Okay, So I just need to add Drupal as an depencencies?

Right now I only have: 

  dependencies:
    - core/modernizr
    - core/jquery

Comment: @Thomashdk – Yupp! :)

Comment: @Thomashdk – `core/drupal`

Comment: Hmm that didn't help ? I added  -core/drupal as an depencencies

Comment: @Thomashdk – Flush your caches twice at least :D

Comment: I think it's funny that the word are in the drupal translation dashboard.. But it gives an error when loading the page where it's used.. ?

Comment: @Thomashdk – That's really strange, yes. OK, so now please adjust your code as close as possible to match the samples on https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview. Especially pay attention to `Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = { ...` and please remove that single `;` from the start of your snippet as in your question.